# R: Creating id by ordered column in data table not working correctly

Tags: r, datatable

I am trying to create a unique ID column based on a sorted column in a data table. I have reproduced a simple example here but I am not getting the ID in the correct order.

```
t <- data.table(YEAR = c(2007, 2009, 2011, 2001, 1994, 2005))
t[, id := order(YEAR)]
```

It is returning the following:

```
   YEAR id
1: 2007  5
2: 2009  4
3: 2011  6
4: 2001  1
5: 1994  2
6: 2005  3
```

But I was expecting:

```
   YEAR id
1: 2007  4
2: 2009  5
3: 2011  6
4: 2001  2
5: 1994  1
6: 2005  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this mistake before. You want `rank`

```
t[, id := rank(YEAR)]

   # YEAR id
# 1: 2007  4
# 2: 2009  5
# 3: 2011  6
# 4: 2001  2
# 5: 1994  1
# 6: 2005  3
```

Comment: Wow, that was frustrating! Thanks for you answer. I have seen another answer on stack overflow referencing order as the proper way to do this so that's what I was trying. Do you know internally what order is doing that is different than rank?

Comment: `order` will return the index of the sorted vector. `1994` is first after sort, but `5th` in the vector